# Re-binding controls by changin app.config

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, connection-string

This question may have been asked and answered before, but I do not know how to search for it.

**The situation:**

I have a `Winforms` application with many bound controls. We have four testing environments and currently, I have been connecting to each data source and importing all data tables and stored procedures using the `Data Source Configuration Manager` then having the connection string information stored in my app.config file. When I call the connection string, I am using My.Settings.[connection string name].ToString (*my first problem*).

For all data bound controls (mostly `datagridview`), I remove the old data set + the table adapter and all binding sources before dragging the new data set + table adapter and binding sources. I have a `Public Sub` that clears and rebinds all of my controls, but the code calls for the specific name of each data source (see below for example).

```
Public Sub SetRegionDEBindings(ByVal errorCode As String, ByVal Region As String)
    Try
        Dim selectLOMAbyRegion As New BindingSource
        selectLOMAbyRegion = Me.SpSelectLOMABindingSource

        Me.SpSelectLOMATableAdapter.Fill(Me.PrdGISDataSet.spSelectLOMA, errorCode, Region)

        Me.dgDE.DataSource = selectLOMAbyRegion
        Me.bnDE.BindingSource = selectLOMAbyRegion

        Me.txtDEIssueDte.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", selectLOMAbyRegion, "IssueDte", True))
        Me.txtDECaseNum.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", selectLOMAbyRegion, "CaseNum", True))
        Me.txtDECommNum.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", selectLOMAbyRegion, "CommNum", True))

        With Me.dgDE
            Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "DERegion"
            Me.StateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "DEState"
            Me.LatitudeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "Latitude"
            Me.LongitudeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "Longitude"
            Me.IdLOMADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.DiskNumDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Visible = False
            Me.InsertDteDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.LOMAStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.NotesDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.StateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.SupercedeDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.Visible = False
            Me.UpdatedDteDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = False
        End With

        Me.dgDE.Visible = True
        Me.dgDE.Rows(0).Selected = True
        Me.dgDE.BringToFront()

        If Me.dgDE.Rows(0).Cells("LOMAStatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString = "2" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Warning: this case number has been previously inserted.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error setting data entry bindings: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**My questions:**

1. Should I create my app.config file from scratch?
2. If I need to change a server environment, can I just change the app.config file (and call `Configuration.ConfigurationManager` instead of `My.Settings...`)?
3. If I change the app.config file, how would I re-bind my data sources without opening the solution, re-creating the data sources, and cleaning/re-building? (Because currently, I connect to the new `data source`, drag the binding sources onto my control, and update the dataset code manually)

**I have looked here:**

[How To Change The Connection String saved in My.Settings in VB 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069691/how-to-change-the-connection-string-saved-in-my-settings-in-vb-2010)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171889(v=vs.90).aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7483b816-be7a-4204-a4d3-cfb14b2aae26/how-to-dynamically-change-connection-string-in-generated-dataset-class?forum=adodotnetdataset

But, like I said, I'm not sure if I'm searching for the right answer.

Comment: What's the problem exactly and what do you want to do?

Comment: I need to be able to change the connection string in the app.config file and have the data sources within the application re-bind to that connection string automatically (without going in to the solution, dragging the correct data source elements on to my controls and cleaning/rebuilding)

Answer (score 1):

### Change Connection String at Run-Time

To change connection string dynamically at run-time you should apply some small changes in your application. (I Suppose the name of your connection string is `MyMainConnectionString`)

1. Change the `MyMainConnectionString` at your `Setting` file.

   - Open settings in designer
   - Select the connection string value and copy it for example `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True`
   - Change the `Type` to `string`
   - Change the `Scope` to `User`
   - Paste the copied value to `Value`
2. From now on when you want to add a `TableAdapter` to your `DataSet` in the wizard, choose to not save the connection string.

Now you have a normal string setting `MyMainConnectionString` that can be changed at run-time and can be saved.

You can set the value this way:

```
My.Settings.MyMainConnectionString= "Some New Value"
```

The value also can be set using some other predefined properties like for example `DebugConnectionString`, `TestConnectionString`, `ProductionConnectionString` and set this value based on some criteria or other setting this way:

```
My.Settings.MyMainConnectionString = My.Settings.TestConnectionString
```

To save the settings, you can use:

```
My.Settings.Save()
```

### Change Connection String at Design-Time

You can simply change the value of your connection string in `Setting.settings` file.

### Change Connection String for Deployed Application

You can change the value of connection string in `yourApplication.exe.config`.

Comment: When you say "Settings" file, you mean App.config or another file?

Comment: No I don't mean app.config I mean the `Settings.settings` In solution expand `My Project` node and double click on `Settings.settings` to open it.

Comment: I wouldn't need to change the connection string once the application executes, I'd need the ability to change it before the application executes. But I could apply the same idea to the App.config file, correct?

Comment: **If you want to change the value at run-time** I think this solution is the ultimate solution that makes changing connection strings really easy. **If you want to change the value at build/debug time** You can simply change the value of that property using settings file. **If you want to change the value for an application that is distributed** You can change yourApplication.exe.config.

Comment: The important common point in those 3 solutions id you don't need to change app.config manually.

Comment: Additional to this answer, you may want to read my post here about [changing default settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32532720/3110834) that is applicable only on deployed applications.

Comment: Let me know if you this answer and the other answer is helpful :)

Comment: This is VERY helpful, the main issue is if our production servers have to go into disaster recovery, so via the solution may not be the best option (it would require me (the developer) to be here to make the change). Our tech support has a process put in place already to change the App.config files of our existing applications when this happens, I just want to follow suit.

Comment: I will continue to look into your answer--I do believe you've given me the resources I need. I'll mark it as the answer as soon as I can confirm. Thank you so SO much.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, you can vote for answers too when you find them helpful :)

Comment: About the disaster, there are many solutions that don't need the developer, **for example** you can create a setting form and let the user to change the settings values and save the settings **or** you can use a mirror server in connection string **or** ...

Comment: It would be great if you find the answer acceptable :)

Comment: Unfortunately the correct answer was you can't rebind data sources in a WCF application from the app.config file. The clean/build solution is the only option, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My answer is general and based on your question is about windows forms. And based on my experience is completely true in windows forms. I don't have any idea about why you mentioned **wcf** in this comment?